# Convert list to binary values using one-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have one column in **CSV** file. Each cell in the column has multiple values in a list. For e.g. one cell would contain `['A', 'B', 'C']` and the other `['B', 'D']`. I want to apply `one-hot encoding` to this column to convert to binary values to use for machine learning.

Please let me know how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input is csv file, so there are no lists but strings. So remove `[]` and use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) along with removing trailing `'` in column names:

```
df = df['col'].str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(', ')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip("'")
```

If there is some processing required to convert strings to lists use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) for improved performance:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['col']),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df)
```